# Handle Laravel QueryException and show custom error page using XAMPP

Tags: laravel, apache, exception, xampp, custom-error-pages

I'm locally developing a Laravel website using XAMPP. To make the site works, I obviously have to turn on the Apache service and it does work indeed. What I want to be able to do is to handle the case when the apache server is down and show my error message. I mean, if I purposely turn off Apache, I receive this error Exception:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused.
 (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = test@yahoo.it limit 1)
```

This is the image: https://pasteboard.co/JegwA2Y.png

Here comes my question. How can I show for example one of my custom error pages instead of this default Laravel QueryException? Where to catch the exception?

Even though my app is not on production mode, I'd still like to show the errors properly.

Thanks!

Comment: That does not sound like the Apache is down.  That sounds like MySQL is down.  If apache was down, you would get a "This site can’t be reached" error.

Answer (score 1):

You must change `render` method in `App\Exceptions\Handler` class. You can read details in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/errors#render-method).

Sample Code:

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    // Custom render.
    if ($exception instanceof QueryException) {
        return response()->view('errors.query', [], 500);
    }

    // Add extra custom render.
    if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        return response()->view('errors.not_found', [], 500);
    }

    // Default render.
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: It seems like the right thing to do but it doesn't work, I can't understand why..

Comment: This is the right way for rendering error. But your problem is not this. When apache is down, how do you serve your application? This sql query for session: `select * from users where email = test@yahoo.it limit 1` but how laravel application running when web server is down? How did you access this situation, because when web server is down you cannot access site. Your question does not explain your  development environment. Please describe.